# div hides onmouseover event on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div and a simple jQuery code that calls the div on an 'onlclick' event and properly hides on 'onmouseout' event. The problem is when I put a text or a link inside this div and move a cursor over the text / link in this div - it triggers  out() function effect and dissappears - even if the cursor is still inside the div. Why is that so ? Thanks for comments.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#sample {
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:200px;
background-image:url(images/img.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="javascript:show();" >link</a>
<div id="sample" onmouseout="out()"><a href="">THIS IS TEXT</a></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#sample").hide();
});

function show() {
$("#sample").fadeIn('slow');

}

function out() { 

$("#sample").fadeOut('slow');

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove JavaScript code from HTML
and try this.

```
  $(function(){

   $("#sample").hide();
    $("a").click(function() {

        $("#sample").fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });    
    $("#sample").mouseout(function() {
        $("#sample").fadeOut('slow');
    });

})();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoop26667/djFfF/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

In the document ready function add this

```
jQuery("#sample").mouseleave(out);
```

and remove the onmouseout code from the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a>` element is inside the `#sample` element, so running fadeOut on `#sample` will hide it, and everything inside it.
To keep the `<a>` you need to place it outside `#sample` in the html.

Oooh, no I get it, try this instead of the inline stuff:

```
$("#sample").hide();

$("a").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#sample").fadeIn('slow');
});


$("#sample").mouseleave(function() {
$("#sample").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Here's a Fiddle, not the way I would do it, but the closest I could get to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/GkSGz/

Comment: I have placed the link outside the #sample and positioned it to place on the #sample div - it still hides when you move over it...